# Cannot figure out how to convert a String to a char[]

Tags: android, string, android-edittext

I’m creating a TextView dymacally and trying to set a default value that is stored in a string.  I’m assuming I get a error because the setText takes in a char[].  I cannot figure out how to convert a string to a char[]

```
String s = new String("test");
t = new EditText(this); 
t.setText(s,0,4);
```

Ted

Comment: `setText` takes a `CharSequence`, which `String` extends. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the string to a char array like this:

```
char [] result = s.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call `setText` and pass it the String.

```
String string = new String("test");
  text = new EditText(this); 
  text.setText(string);
```